# Where is the best position for the adverb "obviously" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, adverb-position

Which of the numbered positions is the best for the adverb "obviously" in the following sentence?

Jim is totally aware of the problem but [1] Jack [2] is [3] not [4].

For each of the numbered options you can find instances here or there. Some look kind of awkward, though.

Comment: Option [3] is correct.

Comment: @peerless Why is it "correct"?

Comment: Most suitable...

Comment: Each depends on what you want to emphasize. For [4] to work, maybe you would need a comma after 'not,' or use 'obviously so.' Just ending 'not obviously' feels like something's missing.

Comment: All four are valid in different contexts.

Comment: It is simply wrong to close this question. It is an obvious question for non-native speakers (that is why I am here, btw, to get the answer to the same question). And it is not at all "opinion-based" to learn that all positions are valid and none of them are clearly idiomatically better. For many similar questions, native speakers agree on things like "Obviously, [3] is awkward, everyone knows that.". (And there may also be native speakers who would like this question answered.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the emphasis you want and how you want the sentence to read.

[2] and [4] stick out more to me, whereas [1] and [3] don't break up the sentence.

For example:
"Jim is totally aware of the problem but Jack *obviously* is not." The *obviously* sticks out whereas "Jack is obviously not" doesn't interrupt the flow.

Answer (score 1):

there is no (linguistically) "best" placement.  this is a stylistic/rhetorical issue.  (With the caveat that you need  commas in some placements, e.g. 2 and 4)